# Request to mods: Can we please delete this answer which doesn't use a single Hindu source?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, sources-and-citations, deletion

[This answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/37985) to [*Did Ramayana occur 1.6 million years ago?*](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9009/did-ramayana-occur-1-6-million-years-ago) doesn't cite a single source from Hindu scriptures, commentaries or even books written by scholars of Hinduism.

The three citations used are:

- [a News article](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2018/07/12/french-farmer-kept-quiet-finding-skull-first-ever-four-tusked) titled "French farmer who found near mythical remains of elephant ancestor kept it to himself to avoid fossil hunters"
- [An article on Gomphotheres](https://ucmp.berkeley.edu/mammal/mesaxonia/gomphotheriidae.php) by University of California Museum of Paleontology
- [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gomphothere)  on Gomphothere

**Request to mods**: Since the answer doesn't draw its conclusions from a single Hindu source, can you please delete this answer?

Comment: That is a great question. I think it can get more good answers but unfortunately not on this site. Maybe we can migrate it to somewhere else? @mods?

Comment: Whatever may be the difference of opinions that we have between us, I should acknowledge that I have learnt something from you.  Thanks for sharing your valuable thoughts with me @sv.

Comment: @Mr_Green, that question was already closed off as scientific speculation. Should we retroactively delete answers that don't have proper sources (after we determine what proper sources are) for all previous questions ?

Comment: @ram I am not sure about that. IMO, we should not if they are popular as the question stated by OP here.

Comment: @Mr_Green - Then why delete it or migrate it . Let it be there as closed . It will help guide future members in what is considered to be valid in HSE

Comment: @Carmensandiego I feel better to migrate it as the community can contribute to providing better answers which they can't do if the post is closed.

Comment: @Mr_Green - perhaps it can be copy pasted on another SE site. But I feel it does serve a purpose staying closed in here